Audio Skipping / Stuttering in Voice Call
I've set up a bot to continuously play songs in a radio style (one after the other), however I noticed that the songs seem to stutter every ~10 seconds. In researching this, it seems like some part of the loop is probably overusing CPU power, but I'm not entirely sure where or what would be an optimal way to improve it if so. Songs are not being streamed, but instead of downloaded.

@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def check_time(): # Runs every second and checks the time.
    #loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

# ----- CHECK IF IMAGE EXISTS OR NOT ------------------------------------------------

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    today = datetime.date.today()
    cur_date = (today.month,today.day)
    christmas_channel = BOT.get_channel(christmas_channel_id)
    weekday_number = today.weekday()
    image_save = "generated_images/" + str(today) + ".png"
    file_check = os.path.isfile(image_save)
    guild = BOT.get_guild(guild_id)
    public_radio = BOT.get_channel(public_radio_channel_id).members
    waiting_radio = BOT.get_channel(radio_wait_channel_id).members
    if running_on_pi:
        voltage = get_core_voltage()
    else:
        voltage = ""
    
    radio_channels = BOT.voice_clients
    if len(radio_channels) > 0:
        song_playing = radio_channels[0].is_playing()
    else:
        song_playing = None
    
    if len(public_radio) >= len(waiting_radio):
        await toggle_radio("move_in")
    elif len(public_radio) == 0:
        await toggle_radio("move_out")
        
    if song_playing == False:
        await choose_song(song_playing,radio_channels)
    
    print(now, days[weekday_number].capitalize(), file_check, song_playing, voltage)


@check_time.before_loop # Wait for the bot to be ready before we start the loop
async def before_bot():
    await BOT.wait_until_ready()

@BOT.event # Bot turns on
async def on_ready():

    try:
        check_time.start()
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BOT.run(TOKEN)

The bot is running on a raspberry pi (checks voltage for surge protection), and has a few other supplemental functions such as daily images (why it checks file presence and date). Please let me know if any issues are apparent, thank you.
